# Handling Alert box on page load

Tags: selenium, javascript

Is there any way to identify the `JavaScript` alert box (on page load) in selenium IDE?
I used commands like "storAlert", "assertAlert" etc. But selenium not identifying alert box.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far, and explain what's going wrong - do you get an error, or does it run but fail to extract the data?

Comment: Is the alert box visible to you? If so, are you sure it is a javascript alert box? Most probably it is not, because when you are running selenium IDE, java script popups does not appear. This is what is mentioned in official site. When running under Selenium, JavaScript pop-ups will not appear. This is because the function calls are actually being overridden at runtime by Selenium’s own JavaScript. Check this section once more... http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#alerts-popups-and-multiple-windows